# File Cleaning Service

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, sleep

As a requirement in Android OS phone, I am developing an app which will clean up a particular folder in a specified interval of time, say every 30 minutes.

I can run a service and clean up the folder every 30 mins. I have few questions over this,

1.Service has onStartCommand, which will be executed when the service starts, can I call a function here which has a Handler which runs every 30 minutes? Example

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    cleanUpData();
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

public void cleanUpData()
{
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // call the function again
        cleanUpData();
    }
    }, "30 mins");
}
```

This code iterates the cleanUpData every 30 mins. 
a. Is this correct? 
b. Will this hamper the performance?
c. Should I use a separate thread as mentioned in numerous tutorials?
d. Should I use a service after-all? Or is there any other method?

2. AlarmManager provides the scheduled repeated alarms, but this does not work when the phone is in sleep mode. I do not want to wake up the screen as it does not require any human interaction. Can I ignore AlarmManager? Or does AlarmManager has functionality to run the code even when the phone is in sleep mode and phone wake up is false?

Please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes. you can have a separate method inside onStartCOmmand() method.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a separate thread for cleaning up the folder.I will not suggest you to use handler inside a service as it runs in the same process as app so a long running operation can make it unresponsive,instead of this use intentservice as it runs on its own thread.
And for the device sleep problem fire an broadcast receiver and acquire custom wake up lock in this broadcast receiver and then invoke your service from here.

Comment: 1. The intentservice will quit service once there is no pending job, so I dont think I can use intentservice, please suggest if otherwise. 2. I do not want to wake up device unnecessarily. The wakeup probably turns the display ON, that should not happen. Can it be done?

Comment: yes intent service will quit when its work is done but you can start it again by the broadcast receiver in every 30 minutes as you will create a broadcast in every 30 min.I don't know that you can wake up a device without waking its display but one thing you can do acquire the wakelock when the service starts and release it or set the device to sleep as the service is finished

Comment: I will use a new thread as you suggested (you are right) and can I use Thread.sleep() to wait for 30 mins instead of a broadcast? Will it be harmful?

Comment: i won't recommend that you sleep the thread as it will hold the resources and memory as a sleeping thread do not release the resources so holding the resources for that much time can be troublesome