# Scheduled Execution of Process

Tags: android, android-service, sleep, schedule, thread-sleep

As a requirement in Android OS phone, I am developing an app which will clean up a particular folder in a specified interval of time, say every 30 minutes.

I have tried this using services, check my other posting [stackoverflow: file-cleaning-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602630/file-cleaning-service)

I am trying to find a best method to execute the file cleaning operation.

1. Should I use a service with broadcasting (or a Handler)?
2. Should I perform it within the app without using a service? The app can hide itself and perform task in the background. Is this approach is good? My point is why should I use a service if the service is just sleeping for a specified time, why same cannot be achieved in the app itself?
3. Is there any other method through which I can achieve this?

I do not want to wake up the screen, hence I do not want to use AlarmManager.

So please help me with best solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `AlarmManager` does not wake up the screen. Your only practical options for doing what you want involve `AlarmManager` (or `JobScheduler` on Android 5.0+).

Comment: AlarmManager doesnt work in sleep mode if wake up not enabled. And I do not want to wake up the device every 30 mins.

Comment: "AlarmManager doesnt work in sleep mode if wake up not enabled" -- you need to use a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm, which has nothing to do with the screen. "And I do not want to wake up the device every 30 mins" -- then you will not be able to delete your files every 30 minutes by any means. If the CPU is in sleep mode, your code will not run, no matter how you set it up, *unless* you use a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm to wake up the CPU.

Comment: Oh, I thought wake-up will wake up the screen also, I will give it a try. Thanks.